# Может ли цикл foreach принимать несколько переменных?

Tags: java

Как известно в цикле `for` можно объявить две переменные одного типа и работать с ними в этом цикле:

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i > 10; i++, j++){
    // code
}
```

Можно ли сделать что-то такого в цикле `foreach`, типа:

```
//Class1[] и Class2[] имеют одинаковые размеры
Class1[] class1;
Class2[] class2;

for(Class1 class1, Class2 class2 : c1, c2){
    // тут работа с c1.getMethod(), c2.getMethod();
}
```

Comment: Нет, нельзя.​​‌‌‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌​​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​

Comment: Невозможно ли в случае равности размеров массивов классов сделать так: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { class1[i].getMethod(); class2[i].getMethod(); };`?

Comment: Напишите как ответ, чтобы была возможность принять его.